# How can I draw axes with a 45 degree rotation?

Tags: matplotlib

I have a set of 7x4 plots arranged in a grid using subplot. I now want to add diagonal axes on top of these.

I know you can superpose axes on top of previously made subplots by setting the background to 'none':

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('none')
```

But I can't find a rotated axis thing. Currently I'm trying to use a top view 3D axes, but I'm far from a usable solution there.
I'm willing to accept drawing the axis+ticks by hand, if this is the only way possible.

**EDIT**: using the `floating_axis` module, I was able to draw rotated (and sheared) axes, but unable to edit the ticks, which is very necessary for what I need. The following snippet demonstrates adding a `floating_axis` to an existing figure `fig`. Any manipulation of the axes' ticks fails.

```
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.floating_axes as floating_axes

trafo = Affine2D().skew_deg(-10,-10).rotate_deg(45)
grid_helper = floating_axes.GridHelperCurveLinear(trafo, extremes=(0, 4, 0, 4))
artistax = floating_axes.FloatingSubplot(fig, 111, grid_helper=grid_helper)
artistax.set_axis_bgcolor('none')
artistax.axis["top"].set_visible(False)
artistax.axis["right"].set_visible(False)
fig.add_subplot(artistax)
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at [this example for floating axes](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_floating_axes.html)?

Comment: @tom No I did not find that one. Looks like exactly what I'll need!

Comment: @tom - do you want to share that information as an answer?

Comment: Sure, when I get time

Comment: You know, between my job and parenting duties :)

Comment: Hmm, it seems there is currently no way to adapt the ticks for an AxisArtist... I did get the floating_axis to work, but no custom ticks, which makes it useless for me. Unless I did something wrong... Documentation is scarce :(.

Comment: you want to post the code you have?

Comment: @tom there you have it. For editing the ticks, I tried `artistax.set_xticks`, `artistax.axis["bottom"].??` but nothing seems to actually change the ticks or ticklables. The only documentation I could locate actually suggest using the former (http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/axisartist.html).